# MongoDB can't add new replica set member [rsSync] SEVERE: Got signal: 6

Tags: replication, mongodb, data-synchronization

I have a replica set and I added a new member to the set. The initialSync begins for the new  member and rs.status (on primary) shows `STARTUP2` as status. However, after a long enough time, there's a cryptic `fassert` error coming on the new instance.

Log dump is as following:

```
2014-11-02T22:53:23.995+0000 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:330 virt:45842
2014-11-02T22:53:23.995+0000 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):45038
2014-11-02T22:53:23.995+0000 [clientcursormon]  connections:27
2014-11-02T22:53:23.995+0000 [clientcursormon]  replication threads:32
2014-11-02T22:53:25.427+0000 [conn2012] end connection xx.xx.xx.xx:1201 (26 connections now open)
2014-11-02T22:53:25.433+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from xx.xx.xx.xx:1200 #2014 (27 connections now open)
2014-11-02T22:53:25.436+0000 [conn2014]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
2014-11-02T22:53:26.775+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from xx.xx.xx.xx:1058 #2015 (28 connections now open)
2014-11-02T22:53:26.864+0000 [conn1993] end connection xx.xx.xx.xx:1059 (27 connections now open)
2014-11-02T22:53:29.090+0000 [rsSync] Socket recv() errno:110 Connection timed out xx.xx.xx.xx:27017
2014-11-02T22:53:29.096+0000 [rsSync] SocketException: remote: xx.xx.xx.xx:27017 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [168.63.252.61:27017] 
2014-11-02T22:53:29.099+0000 [rsSync] DBClientCursor::init call() failed
2014-11-02T22:53:29.307+0000 [rsSync] replSet initial sync exception: 13386 socket error for mapping query 0 attempts remaining
2014-11-02T22:53:36.113+0000 [conn2013] end connection xx.xx.xx.xx:1056 (26 connections now open)
2014-11-02T22:53:36.153+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from xx.xx.xx.xx:1137 #2016 (27 connections now open)
2014-11-02T22:53:36.154+0000 [conn2016]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
2014-11-02T22:53:55.541+0000 [conn2014] end connection xx.xx.xx.xx:1200 (26 connections now open)
2014-11-02T22:53:55.578+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from xx.xx.xx.xx:1201 #2017 (27 connections now open)
2014-11-02T22:53:55.580+0000 [conn2017]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }
2014-11-02T22:53:56.861+0000 [conn2015]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, user: "root", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2014-11-02T22:53:59.310+0000 [rsSync] Fatal Assertion 16233
2014-11-02T22:53:59.723+0000 [rsSync] 0x11c0e91 0x1163109 0x114576d 0xe84c1f 0xea770e 0xea7800 0xea7af8 0x1205829 0x7ff728cf8e9a 0x7ff72800b3fd 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x11c0e91]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x159) [0x1163109]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0xcd) [0x114576d]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ReplSetImpl17syncDoInitialSyncEv+0x6f) [0xe84c1f]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ReplSetImpl11_syncThreadEv+0x18e) [0xea770e]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ReplSetImpl10syncThreadEv+0x30) [0xea7800]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15startSyncThreadEv+0xa8) [0xea7af8]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x1205829]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7ff728cf8e9a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7ff72800b3fd]
2014-11-02T22:53:59.723+0000 [rsSync] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


2014-11-02T22:53:59.728+0000 [rsSync] SEVERE: Got signal: 6 (Aborted)
```

.

The worst part is that when I try to re-start the `mongod` service, the replication begins afresh trying to reSync all the files which are already there. This seems bizarre and useless.

Can someone please help me understand what is going on?

Comment: 1) Which version of mongodb you run, 2) how big in size is the replica set?

Comment: 2.6.1 on the primary and 2.6.4 on new instance. The total size of data is around 16 GB (on primary and one more secondary)

Comment: Your current replica set has 2 members?

Answer (score 0):

In the dump you have above, I see this error

> SocketException: remote: xx.xx.xx.xx:27017 error: 9001 socket
>   exception [RECV_ERROR] server [168.63.252.61:27017]
>   2014-11-02T22:53:29.099+0000 [rsSync] DBClientCursor::init call()
>   failed 2014-11-02T22:53:29.307+0000 [rsSync] replSet initial sync
>   exception: 13386 socket error for mapping query 0 attempts remaining
>   2014-11-02T22:53:36.113+0000 [conn2013] end connection xx.xx.xx.xx:

Which indicates that there is a socket exception error. To me that means that the configuration of a replica is incorrect or the host definded in the replica set configuration can't be contacted (firewall, network issues, mongodb not running)

[STARTUP2](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-states/) indicates that threads were forked for replication. While in the STARTUP2 state, the member creates threads to handle internal replication operations, and then the member transitions to the:replstate:[RECOVERING](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-states/) state. During initial sync, members stay in:replstate:STARTUP2 until the all data transfers and all indexes finishing building. Members in the STARTUP2 state are not eligible to vote.

Running [rs.status()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.status/) from the primary will show you how the primary sees the secondaries and what address (host/port) it's using to contact them. You can also run rs.status() from a secondary after running the [rs.slaveOK()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.slaveOk/) command.

Try connnecting from the secondary to the primary and vis-versa using the mongo client.
Or you can use telnet mongo_host mongo_port_number from either server to see if both are listening to the ports you've defined.